# Pattern for overriding db records

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns

I'm looking for a pattern or code example where a user can enter their own records, that override the default records.

For example a Holiday table the default records may be:

```
HolidayName  Holiday Date  CompanyId
-----------  ------------  ---------
New Year     01-Jan-2016   NULL
Day After    02-Jan-2016   NULL
```

And after the user adds their own holidays (for CompanyId "1234"):

```
HolidayName  Holiday Date  CompanyId
-----------  ------------  ---------
New Year     01-Jan-2016   NULL
Day After    02-Jan-2016   NULL
Another Name 01-Jan-2016   1234
My Holiday   03-Jan-2016   1234 
Joes Holiday 04-Jan-2016   5678
```

How can I retrieve a list of holidays that are a combination of:

1. the default Holidays (where CompanyId = NULL), or
2. the overridden holidays (with the same date),
3. And includes additional holidays entered by the user (by CompanyID).

Like this for companyId=1234:

```
HolidayName  Holiday Date  CompanyId
-----------  ------------  ---------
Another Name 01-Jan-2016   1234
Day After    02-Jan-2016   NULL
My Holiday   03-Jan-2016   1234
```

Not sure if this could done in either a SQL view, Query or C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like if you normalized your data a little more, it would help immensely:

```
Table: Company
CompanyId
---------
1234
5678

Table: CompanyHoliday
Id CompanyId HolidayId
------------------------------------
1  1234      3
2  1234      4
3  5678      5

Table: Holiday
Id OccursOn   IsDefault Name
----------------------------------
1  01-01-2016 1         New Year
2  01-02-2016 1         Day After
3  01-01-2016 0         Another Name
4  01-03-2016 0         My Holiday
5  01-04-2016 0         Joes Holiday
```

Then as [Mark Brackett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242797/209259) mentioned, when you create a new company, create an associated record(s) for in the CompanyHoliday table for the new company of the default Holidays.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, you would just do a full join on dates (since you're only showing a user adding holidays or renaming existing ones):

```
SELECT
     COALESCE(User.HolidayName, Default.HolidayName) as HolidayName,
     COALESCE(User.HolidayDate, Default.HolidayDate) as HolidayDate,
     User.CompanyId
FROM Holidays as User
FULL OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT * FROM Holidays WHERE CompanyId IS NULL
) as Default ON
     User.HolidayDate = Default.HolidayDate
WHERE
     User.CompanyId = 1234
```

However, that doesn't allow a user to *delete* a holiday. You could solve that by creating a User Holiday with an `IsDeleted` flag - but personally I'd probably opt for a copy-on-initialization routine which would be simpler and more flexible. It does require some merging code if you roll out new "default" holidays in the future, but that's pretty trivial.